# mamp pro virtual hosts with wordpress

Tags: virtual-hosts

So I'm using MAMP PRO, to have a better vhost utility. Ok. I've got serious problems with wordpress.

I successfully done this:

1. pointed a vhost reghellin.unbit.it to:
   /Users/stratboy2/Documents/01-LAVORI/perbacco/XHTML/SITO-PERBACCO/
2. Installed wp 3.3.1 multisite here:
   /Users/stratboy2/Documents/01-LAVORI/perbacco/XHTML/SITO-PERBACCO/giboperbacco

ok?

I then:

1. setted up another vhost www.giboperbacco.com to:
   /Users/stratboy2/Documents/01-LAVORI/perbacco/XHTML/test_multisite
2. installed there a normal (for now..) fresh version of wp.

Can't really install it. Every time I go to www.giboperbacco.com, I get redirected to test.unbit.it/giboperbacco

Why?

1 IMPORTAT NOTE: this issue happens only with wordpress. If I substitute wp's index.php under [path]/test_multisite with another index.html or even another .php with no wordpress code, the vhost WORKS FINE.

So I guess it's not really a vhost problem, maybe some kind of wp problem.

2 IMPORTANT NOTE

I also tried to create and point some more vhosts to [path]/test_multisite, but all keep redirecting to test.unbit.it/giboperbacco

Any idea?

Comment: I question whether this is a **WordPress** issue; even if it is, the problem is far too localized.

Comment: You can't really install WordPress in a sub dir of another installation.  Add another dir after SITO-PERBACCO/ for your first install so they will be on the same tree level.

Comment: Chip Bennett: this instance of stackexchange continue to appear really hostile. Really too attention too rules, compared with for ex. stackoverflow.com

Comment: This IS a wordpress problem (Chip Bennett). And I've found the fix by myself: I simply copied a wrong wp_config file that contained multisite directives that referenced the other path.

And I post a simple comment as THE ANSWER just because I cannot answer before 8 HOURS from when I wrote this questions (you know, reputation, privileges..). Sure, I won't wait 8 hours.. 

It's a pity anyway, cause people with the same problem will have harder time trying to find the answer..

Answer (score 1):

have you already installed the WordPress database? if so, the rewrite rule is probably pulling from the WP_HOME, and WP_SITEURL settings.. you can override them in the wp-config.php using something like

define('WP_HOME','http://'. $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
define('WP_SITEURL','http://'. $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);

Also, check the actual redirect using curl

$bash> curl -I http://hostname see if it's actually doing a redirect, or if your browser has it cached.